# How to Hold position on cylinder/pendulum using unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new on Unity and trying to create a cylinder moving as a rigid pendulum. I use a hinge joint in top of cylinder and a motor to ad force.

How do I get the cylinder to hold position and not fall back to "dead" position when the I stop applying force?

```
JointMotor m = new JointMotor();
m.force = 10000;
m.targetVelocity = 0;
m.freeSpin = true;
GetComponent<HingeJoint>().motor = m;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to calculate it manually. 
Create an empty object as a pivot, make the arm and bob it's child objects and rotate your pivot using `Lerp()`. Something like this might work:

```
public class Penduluum : MonoBehaviour {
 public float angle = 45.0f;
 public float speed = 1.5f;

 Quaternion Start, End;

 void Start () {
     Start = Quaternion.AngleAxis ( angle, Vector3.forward);
     End   = Quaternion.AngleAxis (-angle, Vector3.forward);
 }

 void Update () {
   transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp (Start, End, (Mathf.Sin(Time.time * speed) + 1.0f) / 2.0f);
 }
```

}